# Is there any way to open our custom calling screen when the iphone device is locked?

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating custom calling screen in our ios app. But i want to open that screen when the push notification arrives. But how to open that screen when app is in locked or unlocked state(app is in killed or not running state ?.

Comment: If the phone is locked and the user taps the notification then iOS should request the user to unlock the phone so you shouldn't need to do anything.

Comment: @jo Is there any way to open calling screen without tapping on notification ?

Comment: @RahulChopra you cannot show anything on the lock screen and you cannot unlock the screen from an app... so the answer is also no.

Comment: This is definitely not possible. I've done voice/video calls on WhatsApp, FBMsg, Skype, etc, and never have I seen a custom call screen after the screen is locked. There's no way these major apps would forgo this if it were possible.